# Tomcat7 Spring Maven Mysql have different Class objects for the type avax/el/ExpressionFactory;

Tags: java, spring, maven, jar

I use Tomcat7, Hibernate, spring and maven, and i want to use jsf.
After few days, i can't find an issue to my problem.
When i compile my project i have this error:

```
Aug 27, 2013 8:16:32 PM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
INFO: JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations present.  ManagedBeans methods marked with these annotations will have said annotations processed.
Aug 27, 2013 8:16:33 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener$WebConfigResourceMonitor$Monitor <init>
INFO: Monitoring jndi:/localhost/JavaServerFaces/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for modifications
Aug 27, 2013 8:16:33 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized

SEVERE: Critical error during deployment: 
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving interface method "javax.servlet.jsp.JspApplicationContext.getExpressionFactory()Ljavax/el/ExpressionFactory;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader) of the current class, com/sun/faces/config/ConfigureListener, and the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/StandardClassLoader) for resolved class, javax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext, have different Class objects for the type avax/el/ExpressionFactory; used in the signature
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.registerELResolverAndListenerWithJsp(ConfigureListener.java:673)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4701)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5204)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5199)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Aug 27, 2013 8:16:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving interface method     "javax.servlet.jsp.JspApplicationContext.getExpressionFactory()Ljavax/el/ExpressionFactory;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader) of the current class, com/sun/faces/config/ConfigureListener, and the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/StandardClassLoader) for resolved class, javax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext, have different Class objects for the type avax/el/ExpressionFactory; used in the signature
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:273)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4701)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5204)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5199)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving interface method "javax.servlet.jsp.JspApplicationContext.getExpressionFactory()Ljavax/el/ExpressionFactory;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader) of the current class, com/sun/faces/config/ConfigureListener, and the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/StandardClassLoader) for resolved class, javax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext, have different Class objects for the type avax/el/ExpressionFactory; used in the signature
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.registerELResolverAndListenerWithJsp(ConfigureListener.java:673)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:230)
... 8 more
```

Here my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.rop.website</groupId>
  <artifactId>JavaServerFaces</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>JavaServerFaces Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
       <id>java.net.m2</id>
       <name>java.net m2 repo</name>
       <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
     </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>

<!-- MySQL database driver -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.9</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Spring framework --> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.6</version>
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
         <version>2.5.6</version>
     </dependency>

<!-- Hibernate core -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
  <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Hibernate core library dependecy start -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>cglib</groupId>
  <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Hibernate core library dependecy end -->

<!-- Hibernate query library dependecy start -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>antlr</groupId>
  <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.7</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Hibernate query library dependecy end -->


<!-- For Java EE Application Server, uncomment this library 
and comment the rest of the libraries
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
-->

<!-- For Servlet Container like Tomcat -->
<!-- http://download.java.net/maven/2 -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- EL 2.2 to support method parameter in EL -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
  <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
  <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>


<!-- http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>


  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>JavaServerFaces</finalName>

    <plugins>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.3.1</version>
           <configuration>
           <source>1.6</source>
           <target>1.6</target>
       </configuration>
   </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Please someone can help me !
Thanks

Comment: it seems you have packaged a conflicting servlet.jar in your webapp.

Comment: there is no need for you to add `el-impl` in your dependency

Answer (score 2):

These dependency should be provided as follows.

```
<!-- Servlet -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.el</groupId>
  <artifactId>el-ri</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Since tomcat provide those by default.

---

`Aug 27, 2013 8:16:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener` clarifies you faced this while deploying the app, not compiling.

Comment: Jar hell is the most annoying when I started with Java Web App. That is comparable to war against .war when someone start all on their own. @SotiriosDelimanolis